# What is this mysterious elevator instruction: 禁止追逐打闹 or "prohibition of chasing"?

Tags: translation

This instruction can be found on a notice inside the elevator in my office building in Tianjin:

[image: prohibition of chasing]

It says 禁止追逐打闹 (jìn​zhǐ zhuī​zhú​ dǎnào) which is translated to "prohibition of chasing".  The icon next to it appears to depict a man attacking an old lady with an axe, but crossed out in red.

**Question**: How should this actually be interpreted?  Presumably the Chinese actually makes sense.

Googling translations of this phrase's components gives:

- 禁止 = prohibition, and it seems the grammatical structure 禁止[something] means [something] is prohibited,
- 追逐 = to chase (seems to be where the English "chasing" came from),
- 打闹 seems to be something like a playful fight,

and it seems like 追逐 and 打闹 together: 追逐打闹 = roughhousing.  Still, it's not particularly clear, and it doesn't explain the icon.

Comment: http://wenku.baidu.com/view/8778e3250722192e4536f677.html mentions ２ instances
(案例）of this type of bad habit (陋习) and its consequences:１。摔一跤－－缝了五针。２。课间追跑－－撞骨折了 and 我们身边的追逐打闹：肆意的追逐、疯狂的打闹 especially occurring between classes (课间)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't be bothered by the icon. It will confuse you.

And you already know

> 禁止追逐打闹

It is a compound phrase appearing in 禁止追逐和打闹. Usually the sign hangs against the wall in school as a reminder for students to keep themselves safe.

So just imagine what those playful kids do, and you will know what 追逐打闹 is.

Answer (score 2):

English equivalent : No horse play please.

Answer (score 1):

the icon is not proper, nor the english. 禁止追逐打闹 is as a reminder not only for students (as @jiehong-jiang mentioned), but also public areas, saying not chasing each other or fighting with each other, to keep safety and order